# Print a string in TraditionalForm

Tags: output-formatting, output

I'd like to print all in TraditionalForm "f(z)=(z+1)/(z-1)" where f is a function defined in the usual way. What I obtain in Output for f(z) and (z+1)/(z-1) is not the TraditionalForm. What can I do? Thanks

[image: Example]

Comment: You don't need to use `Print`, if you do `With[{x=f[z]},TraditionalForm[HoldForm[f[z]=x]]]` you will get your full expression in traditional form.

Comment: Thank you very much